# How to access span id in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, html

I have an asp website with the following control:

```
    <span id="expTrainingShow" class="clsLink" style="margin-left: 20px;" onclick="GridChanger();">
        + Show Expired Continuing Education</span>
```

I want to hide this based on a condition set in the code behind. Can I access a span id like that? (the website is built using visual basic)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a `Label` instead of a html-span (which is also rendered as span) or you could add `runat="server"`. Setting `runat="server"` allows you to access the HTML element in the code behind just as any other server control, via its ID.

```
<span id="expTrainingShow" runat="server" class="clsLink" style="margin-left: 20px;" onclick="GridChanger();" ></span>
```

somewhere in codebehind(the span is a [`HtmlGenericControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) on serverside):

```
expTrainingShow.InnerHtml = yourText ' set the text '
```

or

```
expTrainingShow.Visible = False ' hide it '
```

Note that `Visible=False` on serverside means that the control is not rendered at all on clientside, hence it does not exist in the html and can be accessed only on serverside.

If you just want to hide it but render it anyway, you should use CSS or `expTrainingShow.Style.Add("display","none")`.

Comment: We need the onlick function to run client side. Will adding runat="server" interfere with the method or just the span id display?

Comment: You can use `runat=server` and use it as any other html control. But note that it won't be rendered at all on clientside if you set `Visible=False` (see my edit). I you just want to hide but render it, you should use css or `expTrainingShow.Style.Add("display","none")`.

Comment: I just need it to work when it is visible. You are saying that as long as it is visible the onclick method (some simple clientside javascript at the top of the page) will be executed client side?

Comment: You can use  it as any other html control, so on clientside the `runat=server` does not exist and javascript works also.

Comment: What is the corresponding .net control for HTML label and span from the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace? I couldn't find any in the class collection - there are for inputs with all their associated types (text, button, radiobuttons, etc) but nothing for spans and labels. Any clue? Well what I need in fact is to be able to get the corresponding control type programatically (eg. Control c; if (c is HtmlLabel) {c.innerText = "something"} ;

Comment: @Sergiu:  `span` and `label` are  `HtmlGenericControl` at serverside if you make them `runat=server`.