# How can I access and set the properties of span control from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, grid

This I what I am able to do with a label control.

```
Label mylabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("label1");
myLable.Text="";
```

I would like to do the same with a span and input control. This is what i tried , but it doesn't work.

```
var myspan = e.Row.FindControl("span1");
TextBox myinput=(TextBox)e.row.FindControl("Textbox1");
```

This is my aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abc" SortExpression="val1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span id='myspan<%#Eval("Sno")%>'>
            <%#Eval("abc")%></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="100px" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abc2" SortExpression="val2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input id='mytextBox<%#Eval("Sno")%>' type="text"
            onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this);" onchange="return RowUpdategrid(event,this,<%#Eval("Sno")%>,'<%#Eval("val3") %>');this.oldvalue = this.value;"
            onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" maxlength="12" class="GridText" style="width: 70px"
            value='<%#Eval("CurrentYearLiquidatedPlan")%>' onpaste="return false" disabled="disabled" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="105px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Post your aspx mark-up too.

Comment: Add `runat="server"` and `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` attributes to your `span`.

Comment: But is there a class Span, or should I use var?

Comment: @Shekar.gvr - Why you are making the id's dynamic like that? Gridview control is anyways going to change that. Doing this will complicate things on server side.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr You can use `var` or `HtmlGenericControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only find server side controls through `e.Row.FindControl`. That means, that you can access only controls with `runat="server"` through `e.Row.FindControl`. Default HTML Tags without `runat="server"` cannot be accessed.

Also have a look at the following SO Post "[How to access span id in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290332/how-to-access-span-id-in-code-behind)".

```
<span id="expSpan" runat="server"></span>
```

When you want to format your output, you can use

```
<span id='myspan<%#Eval("Sno")%>'><%#Eval("abc", "0:n3")%></span>
```

Please look at Standard [Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN for details.

Comment: @STORM--I am trying to set the default no. of decimals that are to be shown in the grids' columns by using string.format() in rowdataboundevent. And unfortunately one of the column happens to be a span. control. So from what you said am i right to deduce that it is not possible for span control?

Comment: Use Eval methods second parameter to format your string like      `<%#Eval("Sno","{0:n}")%>`

Comment: I would have done that if I am sure about how many decimals are to be displayed after the decimal point. But I am getting the value from the database, so i need to do this from code behind by concatenating the {"0:N"} with the database value(Ex:String.Format("N{0}", GridRoundoffDecimal)) P.s. GridRoundoffDecimal is the value i get from the database.@Storm

Comment: Then you could access the span via codebehind and modifiy the innerHtml as descibed in the first link. Or you could modify your value on RowDataBound described in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx!